# Why doesn't this media query work?

Tags: image, css, media-queries

Code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 371px) {

     .img_displayer {
         display:none;
    }
}
```

If i am not wrong, the above code says that if the min-width of the browser becomes 371px the .img_displayer element shouldn't be displayed.  But right now when my site is open in full page, the image is not displayed.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

What your media query is saying is "if the media is a screen and is *at least* 371px wide, then hide the image".

I think you might have intended to use `max-width:370px`

Comment: i did try max-width but it won't hide it.

Comment: +1 You're very fast.  Just before I read your answer about ajax.  your brief is enough to learn :).

Answer (score 1):

Kolink explained it extremely well. Your image is displayed until the screen is 371px in width and then the `display:none` kicks in to hide the image. Here's a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/RvyEj/) to demonstrate. If you resize the window so the Result window is less than 371 pixels your image will appear.